# How can I update an entity with a .yml file?

Tags: entities, updating

I see that `EntityDefinitionUpdateManager::applyUpdates()` has been removed.

Every time I add a new field to a .yml file or I add a new node.type.yml to the configuration directory in a module I am developing, I reinstall the module to see newly added fields.

[Introduction to update API for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/introduction-to-update-api-for-drupal-8)  shows an example where `hook_update_N()` reads .yml files one by one. It would be very inefficient 100 and more .yml files.

I found another packet that allows you to use `applyUpdate()` method but it corrupts the other configuration objects.

I also tried with `drush config:import --source=module/config/install`, but it  corrupts other configuration objects.

Is there a way to update entities using .yml files?